# Does SAP Connector 3.0 Support .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector

Do you know if SAP Connector 3.0 (NCo 3.0) support .NET framework 3.5? Or it only supports 4.0 or later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current NCo can be downloaded for .Net 2 (compatible to .Net 3.5) and .Net 4. Separate Assemblies for the Net Framework versions and for x86 and x64, so make sure to grab the right one.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Appreciate it.